# can't do division function in swift

Tags: swift, average

I'm making the average function assignment from swift tutorial. 
When I write  code like this:

```
func AVG(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
var i=0, sum=0; var avg: Double
for number in numbers {
    i+=1
    sum+=number
    avg = sum/i
}
return avg
}

let Average = AVG(numbers: 3,4,5)
print (Average)
```

It displays an error message showing binary operator "/" cannot be applied to two int operands.

when i perform a simple division like

```
let x = 5
let y = 2
let quo = x/y
```

it works.

What am I doing wrong in the function?

Comment: Declare `i` and `sum` as `Double`

Comment: `Double(numbers.reduce(0, +)) / numbers.count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the AVG function – btw. function names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

A playground displays clear error messages

1. > variable 'avg' used before being initialized

   Solution:

   ```
   var avg = 0.0
   ```
2. > cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Double'

   Solution:

   ```
   avg = Double(sum) / Double(i)
   ```

---

PS: An alternative using the key-value coding operator `@avg`

```
func avg(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    return (numbers as NSArray).value(forKeyPath: "@avg.self") as! Double
}
```

Comment: so I cant just declare a variable with no value and then assign value to it later, because as far as i remember, i could do it in C++

Comment: No, you can't. According to the rules in Swift a *non-optional* variable must be declared and initialized before being used.

Comment: @InVaDeR:  You *can* declare a variable (and even a constant) and assign a value later to it, as long as it is guaranteed that the variable is assigned a value before it is used. But in your function that wouldn't happen if the array is *empty,* and therefore the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `avg` as Double type.

`numbers` has `Int` as type, and `i=0` makes it `Int` as well.

When you are doing `sum/i` it's `Int/Int` and you try to assign it to `Double`.
Swift is not doing conversion automatically - it forces you to convert data types manually.
You can fix it by simply converting both those variables to Double.

Keep in mind that you need to convert Int before doing division - otherwise result will cut the reminder as Int cannot have them. Credits to @martin

Also another problem is that if your numbers array is empty, you may try to return not initialized variable `avg`.

Working code below:

```
func AVG(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    var i=0, sum=0; var avg: Double = 0
    for number in numbers {
        i+=1
        sum+=number
        avg = Double(sum)/Double(i)
    }
    return avg
}

let Average = AVG(numbers: 3,4,5)
print (Average)
```

Comment: With your suggestion, `AVG(numbers: 3, 4)` evaluates to `3.0` and not to `3.5` as one probably expects ...

Comment: Also, bonus question, what's the use of "in" in swift. I'm in the functions chapter and i just cant understand what it's trying to do...